# External hard drive not being recognized by Windows virtual machine on Mac

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive, vmware-fusion

**Using:** VMWare Fusion 8.0.0, El Capitan 10.11.4 on MacBook Pro (Late 2013), Windows 10 x64 (trial version by the way), LaCie 1TB Porsche Design Mobile Drive (USB 3.0, NTFS)

**Goal:** Read/write/delete/etc on external hard drive (I'm just going to abbreviate this as EHD) in virtual Windows environment

**Problem:** Windows can see the EHD because it's listed under 'Devices and Printers', but it's listed as an 'Unspecified' device. Needless to say, it cannot be found in 'This PC' (aka 'My Computer')

**Process leading up to problem:** 1) Plug EHD via USB 3.0 into Mac, 2) Click 'Connect to Windows' (or something like that) when Mac prompts where to connect the EHD to, 3) Ensure it is not mounted in Mac environment and check in virtual Windows environment, it is not in 'This PC' ('My Computer')

**What I have tried:** I have connected the EHD to my virtual machine by going to Virtual Machine --> USB & Bluetooth --> Connect EHD. I have tried using the different USB ports on my Mac. I have ensured it is not mounted in the Mac environment. I have tried mapping it as a letter drive, but it can't be located/identified/found.

**What I know:** I know the EHD works because when I connect it to my work laptop, it shows up under 'My Computer', and I can read/write/delete on it

Answer (score 0):

Try instead connecting it to the VM as a physical disk. ([VMWare Documentation (perm link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160411020457/https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_add_raw.html))

Have you opened Windows Disk Management to see if its listed there? Otherwise you may need to install VMware guest drivers in Windows.

Also, the filesystem on the drive must be compatible with Windows. If you formatted it on the Mac as HFS+, you'll need to format it as NTFS/(ex)FAT/UDF or your choice of cross platform filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is formatted as NTFS and I do not see it is not listed in Windows Disk Management. I will look up installing VMWare guest drivers as I'm not exactly sure what those drivers are

Comment: In both the Mac and Windows environments, I am using Administrator accounts